# Qt: allocating a heap object crashes at ucrtbase.dll

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory

I'm following this article to create a sample Qt Property Browser project: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html

When I build the application, it crashes when allocating the `QtTreePropertyBrowser` object

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qtpropertybrowser.h>
#include <QtIntPropertyManager>
#include <qttreepropertybrowser.h>
#include <QtEnumPropertyManager>
#include <QtEnumEditorFactory>
#include <QtGroupPropertyManager>
#include <QtSpinBoxFactory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    /* create props
     **/
    auto pIntManager = new QtIntPropertyManager;
    auto pPropPriority = pIntManager->addProperty("Priority");

    pPropPriority->setToolTip("Task priority");
    pIntManager->setRange(pPropPriority, 1, 5);
    pIntManager->setValue(pPropPriority, 3);

    auto pEnumManager = new QtEnumPropertyManager;
    auto pReportType = pEnumManager->addProperty("Report type");
    pReportType->setToolTip("Some report");

    const auto types = QStringList{} << "bug" << "suggestion" << "todo";
    pEnumManager->setEnumNames(pReportType, types);
    pEnumManager->setValue(pReportType, 1); // "suggestion"

    /* factory
     **/
    auto pSpinFactory = new QtSpinBoxFactory;
    auto pEnumFactory = new QtEnumEditorFactory;

    /* group
     **/
    auto pGroupManager = new QtGroupPropertyManager;
    auto pTask1 = pGroupManager->addProperty("Task 1");
    pTask1->addSubProperty(pPropPriority);
    pTask1->addSubProperty(pReportType);

    /* add props to browser
     **/
    auto pTreeBrowser = new QtTreePropertyBrowser; // <-- crashes here
    pTreeBrowser->setFactoryForManager(pIntManager, pSpinFactory);
    pTreeBrowser->setFactoryForManager(pEnumManager, pEnumFactory);
    pTreeBrowser->addProperty(pTask1);
    pTreeBrowser->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here's more details about the exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC8A8736AE (ucrtbase.dll) in
>   QtGuiApplication1.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

Comment: If you catch the crash in a debugger, when in *your* code does it happen? Please mark it out in the code with a comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated the code.

Comment: What exactly is the crash reason? aborted? segfault?

Comment: @msrd0 how do i know from debugger?

Comment: I have never run a debugger on windows, on Linux you can tell from the exit code even without running a debugger

Comment: In the output, there's this line `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget`.

Comment: in that case you might want to try changing it to `QGuiApplication` (first line in main)

Comment: still the same crash

Comment: In cases where a `QApplication` *has* been created (as appears to be the case here) the message you're seeing is typically caused by static initialization of a `QWidget` derived object.  That is, the crash actually happens *before* `main` starts.  If that's the case then, as suggested by others, you really need to catch this in a debugger to investigate further.

Comment: how can i catch that in debugger? actually i can execute all the steps before the crash (i put breakpoint at main function)

Comment: If you are debugging in VS, you can have a look into callstack. It shows you where the execution stopped and which nested function calls leaded to this.

Comment: If you ignore the warning message then you may well end up with undefined behaviour at a later point.  If so then the crash at the specified line could simply be a consequence of that.

Comment: this is the call stack:`ucrtbase.dll!00007ffefc6436ae()
  Qt5Core.dll!00007ffeaedb7db1()
  Qt5Widgets.dll!00007ffeaf9a6636()
  QtSolutions_PropertyBrowser-head.dll!00007ffeb018131f()
  QtSolutions_PropertyBrowser-head.dll!00007ffeb01c4220()
> QtGuiApplication1.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)
  QtGuiApplication1.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * __formal, int __formal)
  QtGuiApplication1.exe!invoke_main()
  QtGuiApplication1.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()
  ntdll.dll!00007fff00090c31()
`

Comment: i've built the lib with -library option and then linked the application with it